# The ionic side menu is under ios status bar

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have a problem, I am developing an app to event and the build to android it works correctly, but to ios not, the side menu is under the status bar ios, I don't know wha't is the problem. Would be that I didn't build using xcode?

http://tinypic.com/r/2luc4k4/9

**The codes:**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

       <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
    <div class="list">

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="index.html">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
            Home
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="programacao.html">
            <i class="icon ion-clipboard"></i>
            Scientific Programme
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="palestrantes.html">
            <i class="icon ion-mic-b"></i>
            Speakers
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="ibeacon.html">
            <i class="icon ion-bluetooth"></i>
            What's going on?
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="apoiadores.html">
            <i class="icon ion-ribbon-b"></i>
            Supporters
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="patrocinadores.html">
            <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
            Sponsors
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="maps.html">
            <i class="icon ion-location"></i>
            How to get there 
          </a>

          <a class="item item-icon-left" href="around.html">
            <i class="icon ion-camera"></i>
            Around Santinho
          </a>



    </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: First, your problem is nothing to do with xcode, it seems that ionic stylesheet affect. In ios, the "top" attribute of ".bar-header" should be "20px"($ios-status-bar-height, defined in lib/ionic/scss/_variables.scss). Maybe you could inspect your app in safari and see whether ".bar-header" is existed and its top attribute is 20px or not. Hope this will help you. Regards.

Comment: I put 40px but nothing has changed